# Building a generic item builder with Dart 2

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been using some code provided in an [article](https://github.com/fablue/building-a-social-network-with-flutter) by the author of Lime to build a paginated item builder. This has been working really well until the switch to Dart 2. I have put together a small demo of the issue. The problem is with the stats method. With Dart 1 it would happily accept a Map parameter but now I can only get it to work using dynamic. I haven't quite worked out the reason why yet and I would be very grateful if someone with a better understanding of Generics could explain it to me.

Flutter throws:

```
I/flutter (12798): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12798): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (12798): type '(Map<dynamic, dynamic>) => Widget' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Widget'
I/flutter (12798): 
I/flutter (12798): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (12798): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (12798): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (12798):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new
```

The code is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef Widget WidgetAdapter<T>(T t);

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Generic Type Example',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Generic Type Example', widgetAdapter: stats),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.widgetAdapter}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final WidgetAdapter<T> widgetAdapter;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState<T> extends State<MyHomePage<T>> {
  List<T> data;

  Widget genericItemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (data == null) {
      data = fetchDataPage();
    }

    return widget.widgetAdapter(data[index]);
  }

  List<T> fetchDataPage() {
    List listOfMap = [{"A": "1"}, {"B": "2"}, {"C": "3"}, {"D": "4"}, {"E": "5"}];

    return listOfMap;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: genericItemBuilder,
        itemCount: 5,
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This used to work with Dart 1. Now, for it to work with Dart 2 I have to change it from Map to dynamic.
/// I don't understand why this is.
Widget stats(Map val) {
  return new Text(val.toString());
}
```

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. What Flutter version are you using? Try `flutter channel master` `flutter doctor`.

Comment: Thanks. I am using v0.2.8 (Beta). I have switched to master but still receive the same error. Flutter Doctor shows:

`[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.2.8, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
27.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.22.2)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both your `MyHomePage` and `_MyHomePageState` are generic.

But your `createState` doesn't specify any type at all. So it defaults to `dynamic` instead of `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`.

Change your `createState` to  `_MyHomePageState<T> createState() => new _MyHomePageState<T>();` should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have given that a try and whilst I still get an error, I might be a little closer to understanding it:

`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' where`

Comment: For the `List` thing, I'd change `List listOfMap = [{"A": "1"}, ...` to `var listOfMap = <T>[{"A": "1"}, ...`

Comment: Yeah but that won't work. As this function is invalid. `T` may not be a `Map`.

Comment: Changing it to `var listOfMap = <T>[{"A": "1"}, ...` results in a `The element type 'Map<String, String>' can't be assigned to the list type 'T'.` error. I'm wondering if I am approaching this task the wrong way, but I'm really keen to understand why it worked with Dart 1 but not 2.

Comment: Flutter nearly always had dart 2. The difference is that before it wasn't on "strong mode". Now it is. The error you are refering to are real error even without strong mode. The difference is that before, dart wasn't able to detect them.

Comment: In your case, the implementation of `fetchDataPage` is invalid. As it's incompatible with a `_MyHomePageState<int>` for example.

Comment: If it wouldn't be able to spot them in Dart 1 would I not expect a runtime error though?

Comment: Bugs are not an exact science. They may or may not happens. But your current errors are definitely bugs in your code.

Comment: OK thanks Remi. I tried to put together the smallest reproducible example I could, so maybe in translating it from my main app I have introduced a bug - though the error message ir produces does match the error I am getting from my main app which was working before upgrading to Flutter Beta. I will take another look through my example.

Comment: No, you don't get it. These are not a bug from your sample. These are real bugs from your main app.  It's not because you never faced these bugs that they didn't exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169173/discussion-between-amugofjava-and-remi-rousselet).